# Can I say "under number" to mean the unique code of a registered legislation?

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "under number" when talking about a unique code that is given to a law or regulation entered in some official register?

For example,

> "This law was entered into the register under number **459SK-a.**"

What if there are only numbers in the code (no letters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the how citations are made for the particular register in question. We can say **at** a particular location when referring to US legal code, for example:

> Under the FLSA, employees in executive, administrative, and
>   professional positions, as well as employees in foreign areas, are
>   considered exempt. Rules governing exempt and nonexempt status for
>   federal employees are **at** 5 CFR Part 551.
>
> Compensatory time off can also be approved for a federal wage system employee, as defined **at** 5 U.S.C. 5342(a)(2).

Or **under**:

> Some employees, mainly certain managers and supervisors, are exempt
>   from the FLSA but may receive overtime pay under Title 5, U.S. Code
>   ("Title 5 overtime"). They are limited in overtime to either one and
>   one half times the hourly rate of a GS-10, step 1, or the hourly rate
>   of the employee's basic pay, whichever is greater, **under** 5 U.S.C.
>   5542(a)(2)

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it's possible to place 'registered' right in front of at/under? For example, "According to the legislation registered at 5 CFR Part 551, immigrants are not allowed to drive on the territory of the Republic of Genvivar"?

Comment: @brilliant: No, in a couple of respects that would not be an idiomatic way of citing a particular provision.   **Legislation** is the overarching abstract noun; it is not a synonym for a particular provision of a section of a law. And we don't say that a provision is "registered".

Comment: What if it's a specific provision, can I then use 'registered' right before at/under?

Comment: @brilliant: Not if you want to be idiomatic.  One of the examples shows you a phrase that could be used, **as defined at**.  You could also say **as set forth at|under ...**

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but would this be idiomatic then: "According to the law on driving as set forth at 6789 in the official register, turning to the right on the red light is prohibited"? Do you think I can drop 'as', which is right before 'set forth' in this sentence?

Comment: @brilliant: The preposition **as** is not required there.  Although **the official register** and **turning *to* the right** are grammatical, they are not idiomatic. The sentence could be simplified: *According to XYZ §6789, turning right at a red light is prohibited.* or *Turning right at a red light is prohibited under XYZ §6789*.